# gmail authentication: HTTP request for an oauth request-token failed

Tags: c, oauth, google-authentication, smtp-auth

I'm using liboauth library in c to authenticate my gmail account for smtp communication. The following uri is my get request for accessing refresh and acess tokens:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?oauth_nonce=JtSsdRUwerfiILDiCmMrzRV1&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1472540176&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=%2BeJ8L%2BN63cqtkQvjrojDfoe8CSY%3D&client_id=5499633543492-47g4j52ikumagml1ka7pjemi91m79045.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&scope=https://mail.google.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

I can authenticate by going to the address in browser, but can't authenticate from below c code.

The following snippet (using sample client id and client secret) connects to [oauth](/questions/tagged/oauth) and the `custormer_id` and `secret_key` is returned.

```
const char *request_token_uri ="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
const char *req_c_key         = "s3rsdfsd-87g4j52ikuemsdjemsdfm79045.apps.googleusercontent.com"; //< consumer key
const char *req_c_secret      = "42sdfsdf3KsdfkKHBTiW5L"; //<       consumer secret
char *res_t_key    = NULL; //< replied key
char *res_t_secret = NULL; //< replied secret
char *req_url = NULL;
char *reply;
oauth_sign_url2(request_token_uri, NULL, OA_HMAC, NULL, req_c_key, req_c_secret, res_t_key, res_t_secret);
char * new_str ;
if((new_str = malloc(strlen(req_url)+strlen("&client_id=54s3251492-8sdsdf9045.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&scope=https://mail.google.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob")+1)) != NULL){
  new_str[0] = '\0';   // ensures the memory is an empty string
  strcat(new_str,req_url);
  strcat(new_str,"&client_id=234sdfser-87sdffsdfsdf5.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&scope=https://mail.google.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob\0");
} 
else 
{
  printf("malloc failed!\n");
  // exit?
}
printf("Get:result key from get op:%s\n\n",res_t_key);
reply = oauth_http_get(new_str,NULL);   
printf("reply:%s",reply);
```

I get:

> `"HTTP request for an oauth request-token failed"`

Comment: `oauth_sign_url2(..., res_t_key, res_t_secret);` looks wrong. Remember only values are passed: in this case `NULL`. The statement in question is the same as `oauth_sign_url2(..., NULL, NULL);`